# Move nodes along axis with respect to camera position

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I currently have a rootNode with multiple children nodes attached to it that I want to move around the scene together as a cluster. I currently move it along the x and y axis by using left, right, up and down buttons by changing the position of the rootNode little by little every time the button is clicked, for example for moving left:

```
self.newRootNode.position.x = self.newRootNode.position.x - 0.01
```

This way, the cluster always moves with respect to the coordinate system set when the app is initialized. I'm trying to make it move with respect to the user's left and right everytime they change their position. I've tried doing it as follows:

```
let nodeCam = self.sceneView.session.currentFrame!.camera
let cameraTransform = nodeCam.transform
self.newRootNode.position.x = cameraTransform.columns.3.x - 0.01
```

I know this is not what I want, I must be missing a transform from the camera's position to the root node's position, but I'm not sure what steps to follow.
What would be the right way to approach this? Do I need to reset tracking every time the user changes position? Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Do you mean you want your root node to follow the camera e.g stay at the same position in regard to where the camera is looking? For example always at SNVector3(0.0,-1) in regard to where the camera is?

Comment: @JoshRobbins No, what I meant was, I want the camera position to essentially be the new "origin" every time the user moves, and to be able to move the entire cluster along the x-axis (for example) according to this new origin instead of the x-axis of the origin that was set when the app was initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use this function on your `ARSession` now in ARKit 1.5:

```
func setWorldOrigin(relativeTransform: matrix_float4x4)
```

Which:

> Changes the basis for the AR world coordinate space using the specified transform.

Here is an example (*untested*) which may point you in the right direction:

```
  func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {

    guard let currentFrame = augmentedRealitySession.currentFrame?.camera else { return }
    let transform = currentFrame.transform
    augmentedRealitySession.setWorldOrigin(relativeTransform: transform )

}
```

Not forgetting of course to use this `ARSCNDebugOptions.showWorldOrigin`
in order to debug and adjust your matrixes and transforms etc.

You could also use the code in the `delegate callback` as an `IBAction` etc..

Hope it helps...

Comment: Didn't know about this, thank you! Will give it a try

Comment: not working accurately on my side, can you share your experience @Nina?
cc : @BlackMirrorz